# FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC Not declared but appearing in final build

Tags: android, google-play-console

I do not declare `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC` anywhere in my android manifest but it seems to appear in the final build.

Now I can't publish to play console because I must explain why I need the permission, because I'm targeting SDK 34.

How do I remove this permission

Comment: Are you using this `android:foregroundServiceType:
dataSync` anywhere?

Comment: @404NotFound not at all

Answer (score 2):

Look at the merged manifest -- there is a sub-tab for this in Android Studio's manifest editor. Some library that you are using is contributing that `android:foregroundServiceType` attribute. Once you identify the library, you can either:

- Remove the library
- [Use `tools:remove="android:foregroundServiceType"` in your own manifest to remove this attribute](https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests#attribute_markers), at the risk of your app not working properly
- Supply a justification for foreground service

Comment: add the `tools: remove` didn't seem to work